# Proof of that $\lim_{M \to +\infty}P(|\xi| \geq M) = 0$

Tags: probability, solution-verification

I need to prove that $\lim_{M \to +\infty}P(|\xi| \geq M) = 0$.

I know how to prove that $P(|\xi|>M) \to0, M \to+\infty$, I will call this propostion (1).

So $P(|\xi| \geq M) = P(|\xi|>M) + P(|\xi| = M)$.

We need to show that $\lim_{M \to +\infty}P(|\xi|= M)=0$.

$ 0 \leq P(|\xi|= M) \leq P(|\xi|>M-1)$.

But by (1)  $P(|\xi|>M-1)$ tends to zero, because $M-1$ tends to $+\infty$ as $M$ tends to $+\infty.$

So $P(|\xi|= M)$ tends to zero as $M$ tends to $+\infty$.

So we get that $\lim_{M \to +\infty}P(|\xi| \ge M)=0$.

Is my proof of $\lim_{M \to +\infty}P(|\xi|= M)=0$ correct?

Comment: you are over complicating so much, just note that $\Pr [|\xi |>M-1]\geqslant \Pr [|\xi |\geqslant M]$, now take limits et voilá!

Comment: I thought about it but something stopped me. Now I see that if I know that $P[|\xi|>N]$ tends to zero as N tends to $+\infty$ I immediately get that I want just taking limits. Thanks!